# how to lock a fabricjs bounding box to a group during scale

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, bounding-box

I have some text added to a canvas that i am scaling and when i scale it the text does not stay in the bounding box but rather moves really far below or above (depending on how much its scaled)  I would like to get the bounding box to stay around the text I have attached some images.

**EDIT**: all the code has been added to the bottom

what I have

[image: what i have]

what i want

[image: what i want]

so basically i want the bounding box to stay centered around the text regardless of the curve

ps. all the letters are added to the group via new fabric.Text in a for loop if that matters
also ignore the curve of the words its

```
   var group = new fabric.Group([],{
        centeredRotation: true,
        centeredScaling: true,
        top: 150,
        left: 150,
        height: 250,
        width: textWidth,
        angle: 0,
        // padding: -50
        // adjustPosition: 'center'
    });
    // for each character
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i += 1) {  
        // get the angular width of the text ++ added the scope spacing as well to eventually dynamically change the spacing of the letters
        aw = ctx.measureText(text[i]).width * pA + ($scope.spacing/1000);
        var xDx = Math.cos(a + aw / 2); // get the yAxies vector from the center x,y out
        var xDy = Math.sin(a + aw / 2);
        // is the text upside down. If it is flip it
        if (xDy < 0) {  
            // sets the transform for each character scaling width if needed
            transform = [-xDy * wScale, xDx * wScale,-xDx,-xDy, xDx * radius + x,xDy * radius + y];

        }else{
            transform = [-xDy * wScale, xDx * wScale, xDx, xDy, xDx * radius + x, xDy * radius + y];

        }


        if($scope.flipText === false){
            var letter = new fabric.Text(text[i],{
                id: 'letter',
                top: -180,
                left: -180,
                transformMatrix: [-xDy * wScale, xDx * wScale,-xDx,-xDy, xDx * radius + x,xDy * radius + y]
            });
        } else if($scope.flipText === true){
            var letter = new fabric.Text(text[i],{
                id: 'letter',
                top: -180,
                left: -180,
                transformMatrix: [-xDy * wScale, xDx * wScale, xDx, xDy, xDx * radius + x, xDy * radius + y]
            });
        }



        a += aw;

        group.add(letter);
        group.add(circle);
    }

    canvas.add(group);
    group.centerH();
```

Comment: please add the code with wich you created the group.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi the code has been added to the bottom

Comment: i tried but too much variables are missing to make it run. Anyway transformMatrix is the problem for sure. You have to use angle, scale, skew properties if you want things to work in fabric.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Any idea how you would calculate an angle from a transform? the math for it is over my head

Comment: update to latest fabric and use fabric.util.qrDecompose() it takes a matrix as parameter and gives you back top, left, angle, skew, scale that represent that transform. then use always group.addWithUpdate and not group.add  if you make a working fiddle i try to help

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi areyou talking 1.5 or 1.6.0-rc.1  i dont actually see anything in either one about fabric.util.qrDecompose() and it tells me its not a function when testing with both version

Comment: found it and got it mostly working but the angles seem very wrong when getting the results     if i reverse the `a[0] / a[1]` then it semi works squishes it all really close together  and then upon editng the spacing there are flipping problems but close enough   you should make your comment an answer for me